# Manually change change user .metadata.creationDate in firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have IAP with trial period (2 weeks).
So I need to demonstrate it to apple review team.
But I can't because I create a user to their review and for this user 2 weeks trial period not end & it's far from it :)
Can anybody tell me please, how can I change this user's .metadata.creationDate firebase to make available demonstration of my IAP?

Comment: Hey Ермолай . Any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

The creation date of a user is set by Firebase Authentication when it creates that user record, and cannot be modified.

You will either have to create another user for the test, store a separate creation date somewhere that you control, or create an exception for this specific user's UID in your code.